# What is the domain of this composite function $\sin^2 x$

Tags: functions

I have two functions.

$f(x)=x^2$ with restricted domain $[0, \infty)$

$g(x)=\sin x$ with domain $\mathbb{R}$

I am having trouble determining the domain of $f \circ g .$ I understand that $f(x)$ will not process any negative values, but how do I express the domain $[0, \pi]\cup [2\pi, 3\pi]$ etc.

Thanks !

[[image: Graph of <span class=]$f(g(x))$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaBg7.png)

Comment: It is $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb Z} [2n\pi, (2n+1)\pi]$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy how did you determine that friend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain $D$ of $f \circ g$ is

$$D=\{x \in \mathbb R: \sin x \ge 0\}.$$

Hence

$$D=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb Z} [2n\pi, (2n+1)\pi],$$

as Kavi Rama Murthy wrote in his comment.